# What is the meaning of "you weren't going for it"?

Tags: meaning

Devil took Elliot to hell and suddenly brought him back
to Earth.

> Elliot: you know, fire and the big, horny guy with...
>
> Devil: Oh, just a few special effects. Sort of the Universal Studios
>   tour of evil. It normally works pretty well, but evidently **you weren't
>   going for it**.

Is Devil saying Elliot didn't believed hell very well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "to go for" means "to believe", given that the person who "believes" is doing so because he/she is being deceived into doing so.

Comment: Beware that "to go for it" also means "stop being hesitant", typically when there is a risk or fear involved.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "go for" does mean *believe*. The term originally meant *attack.* More recently, in British slang it can mean *pursue* (a woman).

*Go* is a very common verb in English, as in any language, and can be found in almost any situation. Examples include *go crazy, go long, go last,* and *go out.*

Comment: Your answer is very confusing, please edit to clear. Read my question again.